# Apache ProxyPass: pass requested URL as GET parameter to destination URL

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-proxy

Hi I'm trying to set ProxyPass to pass requested URL as GET parameter to destination URL, but I can't figure out how to write it in the config file.

I tried something like this:

```
ProxyPass ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?url=$1
ProxyPassReverse ^(.*)$  http://example.com/?url=$1
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: For clarity, even if you were using `ProxyPassMatch`, you do understand that `^(.*)$` matches only the part of the URL that follows the "domain"? For example, if the URL for the request is `http://proxy.com/foo/bar/file.ext` the match (i.e., the $1) will be `foo/bar/file.ext`, _without_ the `http://proxy.com/`. Also, any query string following `file.ext` will be automatically appended after the `$1`, but as noted in answer below you cannot in a `ProxyMatch` specify a query string as part of the target url

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the [`ProxyPassMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) directive, if you want to use a regex, BUT as noted in the [`ProxyPass` directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

> *url* is a partial URL for the remote server and cannot include a query string.

As a result, you are going to have to use a [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and set the [`[P]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) to cause the request to be handled as a proxy request by `mod_proxy`.

Although this probably needs some tweaking, a starting point might be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo?url=$1 [P]
ProxyPass /foo http://example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://example.com/
```